# Is there an equivelent of Microsoft.Web.Administration for IIS versions prior to 7.0?

Tags: windows, iis, configuration, iis-6, web-config

Seems this namespace is limited to IIS7 and upwards. Are there any managed libraries from Microsoft or elsewhere that enable you to survey the configuration (just looking for read only config) for a given set of IIS installations?

Otherwise one would have to poke through web.configs, the metabase, and try to cobble it all together.

Comment: They fixed this problem. The fix is called "IIS 7".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there aren't any managed libraries like this for < IIS7.  You can use ADSI to query the metabase, but that's the best I've been able to do.

Comment: Thanks, any idea whether you can get the full set of info that is available from the IIS7 library using ADSI for IIS6? Provided of course equivalent settings existed in earlier versions. What I mean is, have you hit any limitations using ADSI where you weren't able to query a setting in IIS6? Are you mixing the reading of Web.config files with ADSI, or just relying on ADSI?

Comment: You should be able to read everything with ADSI that you could set using the IIS6 management console.  You'll have to separately read the web.config files for the .Net settings.